# SDL Web8: Empty publish transactions result in a warning

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

I got error this "Empty publish transactions result in a warning" error, when i published the page from the parent publication and select the "Also Publish/Unpublish in Child Publications" publishing. any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that for some reason the publish instruction resulted in 0 items to publish. Maybe the structure group is set to not be publishable, or some other reason. Pre Web 8 this would have been reported as a success, with 0 items published, which I think is worse :)

Might be worth running your publisher in debug (stop the publisher service then run `tcmpublisher /debug`) to find out why it is resulting in a 0 item transaction.

Comment: verified the structure group is set as publishable. parent publishing page published successful, but same page is failed in child publication.

Comment: Did you have the option which only re-publishes items that are already published checked? If you di, and nothing had been published previously, you'd end up with 0 items

Comment: Bear in mind that if the Structure group is localised, it can have a different setting for Publishable in the child.

Comment: Dear Dominic, any idea different setting for Publishable in the child?