# Getting warning error while publishing component

Tags: publishing

I have created a new Schema with 3 text fields and one multimedia link field, and I have created Component for the same. Wheb publishing the Component, it's showing the "Warning" state in Publishing Queue.

If I open the details, it's showing:

> Because the number of processed items is zero,publishing was not
> performed.

How to fix this error? Where we can find detailed error in database?

Comment: Hi, please give me bit more details on which version of tridion

Comment: Please refer to the link https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000004682

Comment: This means that for some reason the publish instruction resulted in 0 items to publish. Maybe the published with Republish Only (Do Not Publish New Content) in the Publish Settings tab, or that component not used in any page or not a DCP

Comment: Also find more details on Warning status - https://docs.sdl.com/792152/330049/sdl-web-8-5/if-the-publishing-queue-shows-a-status-of-warning

Comment: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16118/sdl-web8-empty-publish-transactions-result-in-a-warning

Comment: I'm Using Tridion Site 9.1. And Issue is fixed. i have created Dynamic Component template for same Schema and published. it's published with out errors. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Up until Tridion Sites 9.5 you could publish Components in two ways:

- **Directly**, if the Component has a "Dynamic Component Template." This is when you have a Component Template associated with the Schema for the Component and set to publish dynamically.
- **Indirectly**, as part of the rendered content or added binaries of a page or other Component Presentation.

A perhaps standard approach for Multimedia Components, especially for images, is to have them published indirectly. As long as they're linked to from another Component and your templates call `AddBinary()`, the images will be added to the published transport package to show on your website. They aren't technically published in the same way as Pages or Dynamic Component Presentations, but rather appear in delivery with a count tracking how often they're used. When no longer in use, they're removed from delivery (rather than unpublished).

In your case when you want to publish a Multimedia Component's binary directly, you'll need to have a "Dynamic Component Template" as described by @Anand.

For more background on what publishes what, see my [blog post describing the publishing behavior](https://www.createandbreak.net/2013/10/lets-play-what-published-that-aka-sdl.html) before Sites 9.5.

After Sites 9.5, you're able to publish (more) items *without* a Component Template if using the data publishing feature.

Answer (score 1):

User created Dynamic Component template for same Schema and published to fix the issue